# Ag-Grid does not navigate to next page on adding row dynamically

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using Ag-grid used in my React app mapped to some state.

```
const [myGridData, setMyGridData] = useState([]);

<MyAgGrid
    rowData={myGridData}
    pagination
    paginationPageSize={5}
    {...props}
/>
```

Now, I have a form which takes user input and adds a new row dynamically to the grid.

So on saving this form, below code is invoked

```
setMyGridData(current => [...current, newRowData]);
if (gridApi && gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount() >= gridApi.paginationGetPageSize()) {
    gridApi.paginationGoToPage(parseInt((gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount() / gridApi.paginationGetPageSize())) + 1);
}
```

The page size is set to 5. So while I save the 6th record, I want that the grid navigate to page 2 programatically, so that the user sees the new record in the grid.

But here while the grid does add the 6th row, it does not navigate to page 2 and I have to navigate manually to see the 6th record. However, if I am on page 1 and add the next record (i.e. 7th row), it then does navigate to page 2.

So it seems like that for the 6th record, the 2nd page is not yet ready/created.

Comment: Why don't you try to sort by newest date? So user can see the new data on page 1

Comment: yeah, that can be done...but am not really capturing the date added in this case...so need to programatically paginate once page limit is reached

Comment: Check ag-grid [Custom Paging](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-pagination/) section. When new row is added try using `api.paginationGoToPage(4)` to change page number

Comment: yeah, I am using paginationGoToPage , but for some reason, it does not seem to be working in the scenario I have mentioned

Answer (score 0):

React state won't have flowed into the ag-grid component immediately after calling the setState function, due the nature of the react lifecycle. (This means that ag-grid won't know it has that extra row yet at the time you're calling the function)

You could skip the react lifecycle and instead set the row data directly into the grid with api.setRowData, however the approach which leans more into the react lifecycle would be to instead use an effect like so:

```
const [myGridData, setMyGridData] = useState([]);

useLayoutEffect(() => {
    gridApi.paginationGoToPage(parseInt((gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount() / gridApi.paginationGetPageSize())) + 1);
}, [myGridData]);

<MyAgGrid
    rowData={myGridData}
    pagination
    paginationPageSize={5}
    {...props}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...Actually I had earlier tried with the useEffect and it didn't work...I tried now with the useLayoutEffect and that is also not working....Also I'll prefer via the React lifecyle and would ideally want to avoid calling setRowData directly

Comment: Is there some reason why paginationGoToLastPage wouldn't work instead?